# (co-)Horn formulation of Frankl's union-closed sets conjecture

Tags: lo.logic, sat

Based on [comments on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171753/is-every-union-closed-family-of-set-the-set-of-solutions-of-some-co-hornsat-form)
there is simple forumlation of [Frankl's union-closed sets conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-closed_sets_conjecture) in terms of (co-)Horn.

In co-Horn CNF at most one literal is negated in every clause
(Horn CNF where every literal is negated).

Frankl's union-closed sets conjecture is equivalent
to the following:

(A) Let $\phi$ be Horn (resp co-Horn) formula in CNF
in variables $x_1 \ldots x_n$ with more than one
solution. There is a variable $x_i$ which is False
(resp True) in at least half the solutions.

1. Are there sufficient conditions $\phi$ to satisfy (A)?
2. How would a minimal counterexample look like?

My guess about (2) is that one must maximize
the positive (resp negative) literals and
all clauses will be binary of the form $x \lor \lnot y$.